# Avoid Repetition of to be verb

Tags: verbs, metaphors

Is the following sentence idiomatic?

> This running cloud is my grandfather, that cloud my father and that big one my tired mother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what a "running cloud" is, but for now I'll assume it means "a cloud in the shape of someone running". I'm also assuming that the speaker is pointing at three different clouds while speaking.

If I'm right about those things, then yes, this sentence is grammatical and natural.

If the main verb is the same as the first in a list of clauses, then it can be omitted, and the listener will infer it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what a "running cloud" is, but for now I'll assume it means "a cloud in the shape of someone running". I'm also assuming that the speaker is pointing at three different clouds while speaking.

If I'm right about those things, then yes, this sentence is grammatical and natural. If it's about a *moving cloud*, then "running cloud" is incorrect.

If I'm also right in guessing you're asking because it looks like there's two main verbs missing in the second and third parts of the sentence, then it's worth mentioning this: if the main verb is the same as the first in a list of clauses, then it can be omitted, and the listener will infer it.